# Maximum value in an expanding range

Tags: excel, vba

How do I deal with the following task? In cell A2 I have a formula that iterates and delivers results on continuous basis. With each iteration the results are listed in B2, B3 etc.

At the same time in C2, C3 etc I capture the corresponding timestamps. Basically, after several iterations I have a list of results in column B and a list of timestamps in column C. I have managed to code this part.

Now to my problem: As I have timestamps, I will know at one point that there are e.g. 6 results being generated within the 1st minute. The range of results we are looking at is therefore B2:B7.

Based on that expanding range, I need to capture the max result in E2 as the range changes with each iteration until it reaches B7. As I don’t know how many results will be generated within the 1st minute, I need to update E2 with each iteration. Once the 2nd minute starts, I want to be able to do the same and capture the max result in E3. The new range will obviously start in B8 and expand depending on how many calculations are done in A2.

If I could do it for 10 minutes, I would have 10 max results shown in a range from E2 to E11.

Below is my code. Only partly it performs what I have described above. Any ideas how to make it work? Your help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Under the following link I have visualised the problem:
[image: img1]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets(1).Cells(lastrow, 2)
    .Offset(1, 0) = Cells(2, 1).Value
    .Offset(1, 1) = FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime)
End With

Call Generator

End Sub

Sub Generator()
Dim icount As Long
Dim rcount As Long

icount = 2
rcount = 2
For tcount = 1 To 10
    Do While DateDiff("s", Cells(2, 3), Cells(icount, 3)) <= tcount * 60 
        Cells(tcount + 1, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(rcount,   2), Cells(icount, 2))) 
        icount = icount + 1
    Loop
rcount = icount
Next tcount

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through your range using `Step 6`. You can nest another loop that loops `for x = 1 to 6` to find your max. Or you can assign a range and then use the worksheet function Max. Man I wish I had my computer. This looks like a fun one

Comment: The outer loop should be step 7***

Comment: @urdearboy As I might have more or less than 6 results generated within 60 seconds, I cannot use Step 6. In fact, there might even be no results at all or 5, 10, 20 etc.

Comment: Could you graphically show what you have and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JohnyL I have prepared something, however I cannot upload it as I don't have enough reputation yet. Is there a way to send you a direct message? Thanks!

Comment: FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime) make value to String,  So you can't use max function.

Comment: @Dy.Lee The max function refers to values in column B, whereas column C has timestamps as a reference point so that the time difference can be calculated. This is needed to see whether or not one minute intervall has been reached.

Comment: .Offset(1, 1) = timevalue( FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime))

Comment: you can upload your image to imgur.com and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53918454/edit) to add a link to it. SOmeone with enough reputation is likely to embed it for you

Comment: @JohnyL I have edited my post by adding a link to visualisation. Thanks!

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks for your help, I have uploaded the image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track start cell of the minute range and calculate the time difference. If difference is more than 60 seconds, adjust result cell. The comments in code explain everything. Call it in your `Worksheet_Calculate`. Note that you can equally have `Private` variables as `Static`.

In standard module:

```
Private start_cell As Range
Private end_cell As Range
Private result_cell As Range

Sub UpdateResult()

    Dim r%, diff%
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("Tabelle1")

        '// Calculate last added cell
        Set end_cell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)

        '// Check whether the last cell is first cell
        If (end_cell.Address(0, 0) = "C2") Then
            '// Experiment just began. Set initial data.
            Set result_cell = .Range("E2")
            Set start_cell = .Range("C2")
        Else
            '// Experiment is in progress.
            '// Calculate seconds diff.
            diff = DateDiff("s", start_cell, end_cell)
            If diff > 60 Then
                '// Shift result cell
                '// and update start_cell
                Set start_cell = end_cell
                Set result_cell = result_cell.Offset(1)
            End If
        End If

        '// After calculating all required cells,
        '// write down values.
        Set rng = Range(start_cell, end_cell)
        result_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng.Offset(, -1))

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Amazing job, it reflects my intention and performs exactly what I was trying to implement!!!

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is to check the time at each iteration and if the minute is different populate column E on the go.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets(1).Cells(lastrow, 2)
    .Offset(1, 0) = Cells(2, 1).Value
    .Offset(1, 1) = FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime)
    If Minute(.Offset(1, 1).Value) <> Minute(.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
        .Offset(1, 2) = "Change"
        .Offset(0, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Offset(0, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -2)))
    End If
End With
```

You can do away with `Generator` function. It will not be needed here. The additional line compares the minute value of recently added timestamp to the previous value and if its different i.e. minute changed then it marks the row that helps in calculating Max value in column E.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, however your code doesn't reflect my intention. Many thanks anyway!

Comment: @rocka if the code doesn't reflect your intentions, as you say, can you please explain why/how it doesn't accomplish what you want? It would help anyone else figure it out.

Comment: @rocka well I think I got that you intend to calculate Max value from column B. I edited to code to work for the calculation using helper column D to mark the change of minute

Comment: @PankajR thank you for your help. The edited code gives me the maximum value once the range of values in column B has been formed, i.e. the code calculates the maximum only after 60 seconds, although I need to calculate the maximum on the go, with each iteration I need to know what the maximum is. I have uploaded the image, it might be helpful. Thanks again for working on this problem.